# list of figure beyond figure 100

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, horizontal-alignment

how can I align the list of figure when goes beyond 100.  Thanks
[image]

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}%checkmark on table

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\cfoot{\thepage}}}{\slshape \rightmark}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %lets the head rule disappear.
\lhead{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}


\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R}  % Journal abbreviations 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in}  %topmargin control
%%%to use parenthesis in subfigure 1(a)
%\usepackage[caption=false,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\captionsetup [subfigure]{font=scriptsize}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  %to include subsection in table of cont.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}       %change page number style



\begin{document}
%\include{frontpage}\newpage
%\include{abstract}\newpage
%\include{authorshipstatement}\newpage  
%\include{dedication}\newpage 
%\include{acknowledgement}\newpage 
\tableofcontents\newpage
\listoffigures \newpage
\listoftables \newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Foo}
\bgroup
\newcount\manyfigures
\loop\ifnum\manyfigures<150
\advance\manyfigures by 1
\captionof{figure}{foo \the\manyfigures}
\repeat
\egroup


\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: This highly depends on the used packages and documentclass. Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) showing a document which prints your list of figures.

Comment: In the image you can see that from figure 1.100 is when the problem starts. can you see it?

Comment: so what is the problem here? I am confused

Comment: I've made an edit so the current MWE in the question does produce a lof which shows the problem.

Comment: BTW: You should not use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. If you do not like paragraph indention, you should at least use paragraph separation. With a standard class you should use package `parskip` to do so.